# Delphi TFDStoredProc parameter default values missing (MS SQL)

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firedac

I am migrating from ADO to FireDAC. After replacing TADOStoredProc to TFDStoredProc I have the following issue. My _OpenStp procedure opens a stored procedure having default values in its parameter list, and I don't want to pass all those parameters. E.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SearchDocument]
  @User_Id INT
  , @Window_Id INT = 10
  , @Page INT = 1
...
```

The core of my procedure:

```
procedure _OpenStp(
  const AConnection: TFDConnection;
  var AStp: TFDStoredProc;
  const AStpName: string;
  const AParamNameA: array of string;
  const AParamValueA: array of Variant);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if AStp <> nil then
  begin
    if AStp.Active then
      AStp.Close;
  end
  else
    AStp := TFDStoredProc.Create(nil);

  AStp.Connection := AConnection;
  AStp.StoredProcName := AStpName;
  AStp.Prepare;
  for i := Low(AParamNameA) to High(AParamNameA) do
    AStp.Params.ParamByName(AParamNameA[i]).Value := AParamValueA[i];

  AStp.Open;
end;
```

The Delphi code of the call:

```
_OpenStp(SomeConnection, SomeStp, 'usp_SearchDocument',
  ['User_Id'], [150]);
```

According to SQL Server Profiler the call was:

```
exec [dbo].[usp_SearchDocument] 
  @User_Id=150,
  @Window_Id=NULL,
  @Page=NULL
```

TFDStoredProc.Prepare doesn't seem to query the default values of the sp parameters. When I was using the ADO counterpart of my _OpenStp procedure, the TADOStoredProc.Parameters.Refresh method did that job:

```
procedure _OpenStp(
  const AConnection: TADOConnection;
  var AStp: TADOStoredProc;
  const AStpName: string;
  const AParamNameA: array of string;
  const AParamValueA: array of Variant);
begin
  if AStp <> nil then
  begin
    if AStp.Active then
      AStp.Close;
  end
  else
    AStp := TADOStoredProc.Create(nil);

  AStp.Connection := AConnection;
  AStp.ProcedureName := AStpName;
  AStp.Parameters.Refresh;
  for i := 0 to Length(AParamNameA) - 1 do
    AStp.Parameters.ParamByName(AParamNameA[i]).Value := AParamValueA[i];

  AStp.Open;
end;
```

SQL Server Profiler:

```
exec usp_SearchDocument 150,default,default
```

Unfortunately it isn't an option to rewrite the code to pass all of the parameters, I have to rely on sp parameter default values. Is there a way to modify the FireDAC version of my _OpenStp procedure to achieve this goal?

Edit: I don't even have information about the type of the parameters (see the _OpenStp procedure), I only know their names and the values to be set, so I can't create the TFDParams programmatically.

Edit#2: An `EArgumentOutOfRangeException` was thrown after deleting the unnecessary parameters:

```
for i := AStp.ParamCount - 1 downto 0 do
  if AStp.Params[i].Name <> '@RETURN_VALUE' then
  begin
    ExistsInArray := False;
    for j := Low(AParamNameA) to High(AParamNameA) do
      if Char.ToLower(AStp.Params[i].Name) = Char.ToLower(Format('@%s', [AParamNameA[j]])) then
      begin
        ExistsInArray := True;
        Break;
      end;

    if not ExistsInArray then
      AStp.Params.Delete(i);
  end;
```

Comment: Sidenote: don't use `sp_` as a prefix for stored procedures in sql server [See this](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: You are right GuidoG. We've been using the usp prefix for a while, but there are some stored precedures with the "old" prefix to be changed.

Comment: Can't access Embarcadero's docwiki currently (their site is down due to database problems) but if Firedac can't send the `default` keyword for unspecified parameter values, as seems to be evident from other StackOverflow questions, then have you tried deleting items from the TFDStoredProc.Parameters collection for the parameters you don't intended to send any values for?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I wonder if there is a setting _somewhere_ to send `default` instead of `NULL`, but I was unable to find it so far. I tried out deleting the unnecessary parameters, but I received an `EArgumentOutOfRangeException` (see Edit#2 for code).